# Building phonegap android application on Mac

Tags: android, macos, cordova, ant

I am trying to build a phonegap application on my Mac and im thinking i have some errors in my Android setup. When I do phonegap build android im getting the following error

```
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /Users/un/Documents/Github/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/un/Documents/Github/myapp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/un/Documents/Github/myapp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/un/Documents/Github/myapp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

In my bash profile.rc i've added

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/opt/android-sdk
export ANT_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/ant/bin
```

The app works fine in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the platform and add again

> cordova platform remove ios
>
> cordova platform add ios

`